# Just beat Halo: Reach but missed Keyes' and Cortana's end exchange

Tags: halo-reach

What did they say to each other, and what did it mean? I completely missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the ending on YouTube:

The exchange between Cortana and Keys is the beginning of Halo: Combat Evolved! Cortana plots a random hyperspace jump to lose the covenant and by chance discover the first halo ring. The story then continues with you playing as Spartan – 117 in the first Halo game.

Comment: But I though "The Package" that Noble 6 delivered was the info that helped them find the first halo ring.

Comment: A fragment of Cortana was the package, the fragment noble 6 carried was used to analyse the glyphs etc. This fragment was then re-united with the remainder of cortana on the pillar of autumn. Cortana had no information of the location of the ring, the rings discovery was a complete accident.

Comment: So then what was so important about the package?  What fragment of Cortana was that?  Dude, I'm so lost.

Comment: Cortana had information regarding the forerunner technology, thats why she knew so much about the first halo ring. Heres a couple of links regarding the ending: http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=49002789&postRepeater1-p=1#49003653 and http://boards.ign.com/xbox_360_general_board/b8266/195862448/r195872110/

Comment: The jump wasn't random. She used coordinates that were found in Forerunner ruins found by the Covenant on some planet. I forgot exactly what planet.